# Maintaining Excel table range when linking to Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, office365

I am trying to link automatically updating Excel tables to a Word document, and since the file will be used by different people, it should also work across different computers.

I am using the Paste Link function for this, and although it works perfectly as long as I keep the files in the same folder, whenever the file is opened on a different computer and the Excel file location has to be linked again, it forgets the table range and churns out the entire Excel worksheet instead. This seems to be the case for all paste options: RTF, worksheet object, unformatted unicode text, etc. On the other hand, graphs do not have this issue.

Is there a possibility to have the table or its range automatically update without having to manually input the range for every table I use? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is inserting an Excel sheet in Word a possible choice?

Comment: As long as the Excel isn't moved, the link in a Mail Merge should be a permanent link. User merge FIELDS as "links" to data in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to have the table or its range automatically
>   update without having to manually input the range for every table I
>   use?

Try using A **Mail Merge** in MS Word:

Lets Create the "database", or pseudo db, from Excel. In this example I'll name it **db.xlxs**. I will set it up like this.

```
Name:
Alice
Barbara
John Ricky
```

**In MS Word, in this example, let's use the Excel db we just created.**

1. Select "Mailings" tab
2. Start Mail Merge - Step by step Wizard
3. Use default, "Letters". Click "Next" bottom right link
4. Use default, "Use Current Document". Click Next:Select Reciptients
5. Use default, "Use and Existing List". Browse (change file type / Data Source to Excelon the right drop box before selecting Source File).
6. Select the db.xlxs file you created earlier in this example.
7. Open it.
8. Select Sheet1 -- note: First Row Contains Column Headers check-box. Click Ok.
9. Click Okay.
10. Your sheet should be still as is.

**Now to set up the Merges**.

1. Mailings Tab again.
2. Insert Merge Field. This will get the first Name field onto the sheet.
3. Rules: Next Record If: "is not blank"
4. Insert Merge Field Names again touching the Rules you just inserted.

**Pictorially this is how it's done.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Weird... I just stopped by for no apparent reason. And look here, another Noob, one point, never to be seen or heard from again... Took a while to put this together. Well, no wonder I don't come here any more...

Comment: Hey man, sorry that I forgot to respond. I realize that you took the time out of your day to help me out and I really appreciate that!

Comment: @Bram -- hey no problem. I was just ranting. I used to help out a lot on this forum, but not any more because of too many people not getting back and too many old-timers down-voting because of whatever reasons. Hey, now that you are still alive, if this was the answer please hit the check-mark to accept it. Thanks and take care.

Comment: Sure thing! I totally understand your sentiment, especially if it happens often. Do realize that your efforts are being appreciated :-) Cheers